# How to render model property inside html word?

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

theres a model that contain several objects. I'd like to loop through it's collection and render it so it looks like this:

```
<div class = "tab-content" id = "home1">                
</div>
<div class = "tab-content" id = "home2">                
</div>
<div class = "tab-content" id = "home3">                
</div>
```

I've tried many ways to solve this, but I couldnt find proper one. 'home' word is static html content and integer next to it is a c# statement taken from model.I know It's nothing complicated but It's just hard to find.

Eg. of what should it (+/-) look like inside the code

```
<div class = "tab-content" id = "home@p.id">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
<div class = "tab-content" id = "home@(p.id)">
```

`@()` is specifying that it is c# code.